# iCloud storage downgraded to 5GB for no reason

Tags: icloud, downgrade

Some months ago I had increased the iCloud storage from 5GB to 50GB, paying €0.99 monthly. This week I got an "iCloud storage full" message and noticed that storage got back to 5GB.

Any clues?

Comment: Contact Apple - they're the only people who can know.

Answer (score 2):

Just found out that my credit card expired!

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/205124)

Comment: @Icon How is this not an answer to the question? This is the solution to the problem OP was having — solutions don't go in the question.

Comment: I does answer the question, true, but some additional verbiage from the OP with some details about how the solution was discovered would be helpful to others with the same issue. To me, this one-liner answer looks incomplete. I used the 'add additional information' clause in my comment to emphasise this. Perhaps making a mechanism for allowing OPs to enter their own solution into their original question slot would be visually appealing and more user-friendly. Is this a Meta-worthy suggestion, @grgarside?

Comment: @IconDaemon The answer definitively could use some more explanations, but in the context of the question gives enough detail for future visitors. I **strongly** recommend against putting answers into the question text (in any form), it works against all the things this site has in place to work as a Q&A site.

Comment: Fair enough, patrix.